# How accurate is Android's Activity/Transition recognition for trains?

Tags: android, android-activity, google-api, location, google-awareness

I'm developing an application that should be able to detect when a user has got on a mode of public transport, such as a train or bus.

I've seen the Activity and Transition API made by Google, but all of the references to the "IN_VEHICLE" activity are in the context of cars.

I realise it won't distinguish the differenfe between a car or train, but will it say the user is in a vehicle when they are on a train?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty accurate these days, even for trains. I'm a developer for the [NumberEight Context SDK](https://www.numbereight.me/our-tech), and I regularly run side-by-side comparisons of our solution to Google's solution. We have the edge on detection speed, and our accuracy is generally a bit better for everything except cycling, but theirs definitely works well on trains.

Some time in the future, we will release the ability to be specific about which type of vehicle the user is in (it's currently undergoing testing, ~70-80% F1 score), so do check us out! Here are some [iOS](https://gitlab.com/numbereight/iOSExample) and [Android](https://gitlab.com/numbereight/AndroidExample) example projects.